# Checking to see if two arrays have the same values in the same positions

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing code which uses arrays as part of a puzzle, the objective of the puzzle is that the puzzle is scrambled and the user has to enter commands to get the puzzle back to the original. I have saved the original in a variable and the current in a variable which is what the user input changes.

I want the while loop to terminate if the user completes the puzzle so I tried the following code:

```
if (arroriginal == currentarr){
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You have completed the puzzle");
        }
```

This did not work however as when I begun the puzzle any input would result in the completion message. Can anyone help me?? :-)

I am guessing that the '==' operator just checks the contents and not the positions of the values in the array

Comment: Use `Arrays.equals(arroriginal, currentarr)`.

Comment: @RJB hard to say without seeing the code. Try posting the relevant parts, or post an [MCVE].

Comment: Okay i have edited the post

Comment: I'm writing this just to know something more about '==' operator in java.
Operator '==' compares object references, it checks to see if the two operands point to the same object (not equivalent objects, the same object).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` to compare contents of the arrays

`array1 == array2` will return true only if they are same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int [] array1 = new int[]{1,2,3};
    int [] array2 = new int[]{1,2,3};
    int [] array3 = new int[]{1,2,3};

    System.out.println(array1 == array2);//this will print false
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(array1, array2));//this will print true
    array2 = array1;
    //now "==" will return true
    System.out.println(array1 == array2);
    Arrays.sort(array1);
    Arrays.sort(array3);
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(array1,array3));//this will return true
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://ideone.com/UXLdO8)

Comment: Does that compare the positions of the values in the arrays?

Comment: Thanks, how would I fit this into the code I just put in the main post?

Comment: arroriginal & currentarr have same values at same position? Can you share contents of both these arrays?

Comment: arroriginal is the original array which I am trying to match to currentarr to in the puzzle. It is 4x4 and has 16 values which all go up 1 at a time. currentarr is a shuffled version of arroriginal which the user is using the methods rotateRow and rotateColumn to try to match the original, which will then print the congratulations message.

Comment: Use Arrays.sort first if both arrays don't have same values at same positrons. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
int a = new a[5];
int b = new b[5];
```

These are two arrays with some values
First u have to sort the array some how to make the positions identical

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
if(a[i]!=b[i]){
//print arrays don't match
//use some flag that helps u to know that it's a failure
break;   // u have to use break statement to end the loop
}
}
//Now use the flag here using if statement to find if u have a match or not
```

Iooking from ur question .... This is wat I'm getting... Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, less efficient method from the other. The only reason to use this is if you are comparing arrays which are different lengths.

```
int array1[];
int array2[];

boolean flag = true;
int size;
if(array1.length > array2.length) size = array2.length;
else size = array1.length;  
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(array1[i] != array2[i]) {
            break;
            flag = false;
        }
    }
if(flag == false) System.out.print("Not equal!");
```

This basically figures out which array is larger, then loops the size of the smaller array times and checks each element to see if they are not equal. If not, it flags false and breaks the loop.